# Merging PDF files Together

Tags: pdf, adobe

I’m looking for a workaround to not buy Adobe Acrobat since this is the only time that I had needed it since using a computer for the last 20 years and I need to do just this 1 job with it.

I’m trying to use Preview viewer to merge pdf files together and I was successful at doing it just a minute ago yet can’t seem to replicate my steps again. I open 2 pdf files in 2 separate Preview viewers (one being an older version) then drag a page from one sidebar into the next sidebar to correlate my multiple pdf file.

But the Save and Save All option is grayed out and the Save option is only allowed in the drop down submenu under File. It would be nice if they weren’t :/ But I have seen a Save All option button when I try to close the Preview viewer and this document looks like it’s saved somewhere but never says to where and I can’t find the file name under the Search bar option.

Does anyone here know a work around on how I can do this please? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

You were actually doing it correct, its just that when you want to save it, you actually have to export it as a separate file. If you wish to keep the same file name, you'll have to save it as a different name 1st, then delete the original and rename the new one.

Here is the step by step guide:

**Combine two PDFs**

> 1. Open a PDF in Preview.
> 2. Choose View > Thumbnails to show page thumbnails in the sidebar.
> 3. To indicate where to insert the other document, select a page thumbnail.
> 4. Choose Edit > Insert > Page from File.
> 5. Select the PDF that you want to add, then click Open.
> 6. To save, choose File > Export.

**Combine part of a PDF with another PDF**

> 1. Open the PDFs that you want to combine in Preview.
> 2. In each document, choose View > Thumbnails to show page thumbnails
>      in the sidebar.
> 3. Press and hold the Command key, select the page thumbnails that you want to add to the other document, then let go of Command.
> 4. Drag the selected thumbnails into the sidebar of the other PDF, then
>      release where you want them to appear.
> 5. If your Mac has macOS Sierra or earlier, drag the thumbnails
>      directly onto a thumbnail in the other PDF.
> 6. To save, choose File > Export.

[image]

You can view more information and details here:
https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT202945

Comment: well thank you but there is no Export option using Preview Version 5.0.+ any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using any third party PDF readers.