# Merge pdfs sequentially

Tags: pdf

I would like to merge 4 pdfs, `pdf1.pdf, pdf2.pdf, pdf3.pdf pdf4.pdf` together so that the pdfs are spliced, i.e. the first page will be the first page of pdf1, the second the first of pdf2, the third the first of pdf3, etc.

The pdf files are with plain images, no table of contents.

How would I accomplish this? It would be nice to do it from Terminal as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging PDF files Together](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317656/merging-pdf-files-together)

Comment: Welcome to ASE, Michael. @EddGrowl I dont think so. It will need apple script. Although the question linked can be helpful for scripting.

Comment: Do all all the PDF files have the same page count? Do any of the PDF file have a Table of Contents, or are then just plain PDF files with plain pages?

Comment: they are just pdf files with plain images, no table of contents.

Comment: @Michael Klyachman, I've removed "Solved using the PyPDF2 module." from the question as answers belong in their own answer, not the question. Feel free to post your own answer, which you can even accept as the accepted answer for you, and thus increasing your reputation points.

Comment: To the close voters, the possible dup is really not, as it does not cover the scope of this question and because Preview mention in the possible dup does not have the ability to automatically collate multiple documents. As such, it is not a viable answer as one would have to split each document into individual pages and manually collate via drag and drop. It's definitely not a tenable solution for the scope of this question! The file numbers and page counts were just examples and the OP said in a comment "dropping in 1 at a time is inefficient when dealing with a several-hundred-page pdf".

Comment: @MichaelKlyachman Can you please share your PyPDF2 method for doing this?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using a **macOS** *default* built-in, from either the *command line* or its **GUI** app the *action* belongs to.

To do as you requested from the *command line*, in **Terminal**, use the following *command* example:

```
"/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py" --shuffle -o /path/to/collated.pdf /path/to/file1.pdf /path/to/file2.pdf /path/to/file3.pdf /path/to/file4.pdf
```

To make the **macOS** *built-in* `join.py` *script* easier to use from the *command line*, I'd suggest you make a symbolic link for it. As an *example*, if you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`:

```
sudo ln -s "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py" "/usr/local/bin/pdfjoin"
```

Afterwards, you can start the *command* with just `pdfjoin` instead of using its *fully qualified pathname*.

---

Below is a image of an **Automator** *workflow* to show an *example* of how it can be achieved using a **macOS** *default* built-in **GUI** app. Note that it can be modified many different ways to suit one's needs/wants.

[image]

<sub>**Note:** The **Combine PDF Pages** *action*, when used in **Automator** creates a temp file and why additional *actions* are needed to refine the *workflow*. You could just use the **Open Finder Items** *action* directly after and forgo the other actions, but of course you'll need to then manually save the opened new pdf file elsewhere.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I do this in preview:

Open the first one,

Select the others,

With the sidebar « thumbnails » visible, just drag and drop into the sidebar.

Check order but usually they go in by name order...

How I create my exams...

Each one is one page, created in excel with headers and page numbers exported as pdf...

Comment: this does not work, as it just puts the pdfs next to each other. I need it to go 1_1 1_2 1_3 1_4 2_1 2_2 2_3 2_4, where a_n represents the a-th page of pdf number n.

Comment: Don't know what you are doing - just done one exam with 7 pages, started with cover page and dropped the others in... works fine for me. You can drop 1 in at a time if you wish...

Comment: dropping in 1 at a time is inefficient when dealing with a several-hundred-page pdf. I solved this using the PyPDF2 module.

Comment: You did state 4 pdf's in your question, or did you mean 400?

Comment: I meant 4 pdfs, each of which is several hundred pages long. Sorry if it came across differently.

Comment: @MichaelKlyachman - You can thereafter reorder the pages by dragging the thumbnails in the left hand thumbnail column, although admittedly, this is rather tedious. I had to do it that way recently. Could you post your PyPDF2 method as an answer, as I would like to know how to do it that way.