# Merge two pdf to one with their pages merged alternatively

Tags: mac, command-line, bash

I have a PDF A.pdf and B.pdf and would like to merge them both to AB.pdf, where each page is merged alternately so that page 1 in AB.pdf would be the first page of A.pdf and page 2 in AB.pdf would be the first page of B.pdf etc.

I would like to achieve that with an handy command in `bash` on `macOS 10.14.5`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360527/merge-pdfs-sequentially/360536?r=SearchResults&s=9|24.0854#360536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 3rd party app named [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org). SAM stands for split and merger. It does exactly what you're looking for and there is a free basic version. This is a newer version than I have but my version has a link near title bar that read Alternate Mix that will do what you described.